# Can't use ObservableProperty from the CommunityToolkit.MVVM

Tags: visual-studio, mvvm, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to use the new ObservableProperty attribute from the CommunityToolkit.MVVM.  Any time I add it, I get 17 errors such as "The type MainViewModel already contains a definition for FileToPlay", or "Type MainViewModel already defines a member called 'OnFileToPlayChanging' with the same parameter types".  These are all in the MainViewModel.g.cs file.

I'm using VS 2022 Community, and the project has a WPF Application project template targeting .NET6.

Sample code that generates the error is:

```
namespace CorePlayer.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string? fileToPlay;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Visual Studio to version 17.4.0 preview 6 (and making sure the class was marked "partial"), it now works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem.  Searching for an answer led me to this question.
My application is a WPF app on .NET Core 3.1.

I fixed it by following the guidance at the end of this YouTube video, [.NET Community Toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXoNF_kwwUU#t=22m5s).

I chose my second project as a .NET Standard 2.1 project.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, kduenke.  I'll check that out.